# Outdated introduction of the Developer Survey 2017

Tags: bug, survey, survey-2017, trends

The introduction of the Developer Survey 2017 on [Stack Overflow Insights](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey) is (emphasis mine):

> With more than 64,000 responses fielded from 213 countries and
>   dependent territories, our 2017 Annual Developer Survey is the most
>   comprehensive survey of software developers ever conducted. We
>   examined all aspects of the developer experience from career
>   satisfaction and job search to education and sound preference when
>   coding. View the results now. **In a few weeks, we'll share the full
>   data set for you to download and analyze.**
>
> View Survey Results • **Download Full Data Set (CSV)**

However, the full data set is already available. Please fix this.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out -- we'll get on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been fixed -- again, thanks for pointing it out!